# For Each Match in Array Increment by One

Tags: arrays, powershell, contains

I am working on assigning user IDs by taking the first five characters of the last name, the first three characters of the first name, then adding 001 to the end of that string. So, a person named Jo Doe would be assigned "DOE__JO_000" as his user ID.

If the person's name criteria is less than three characters in the first name and/or less than five characters in the last name, I add a "_" until it meets that criteria.

Right now I can find matches and create the naming criteria, but if there more than one match it only increments once if there's multiple matches.

I need to check if an ID assigned to a user already exists in the project, and if it does to increment the new ID by 1?

For example, if there is a user named Jo Doe that is already assigned the ID  "DOE__JO_000" in the project, then I would like to add 1 to the other Jo Doe, giving him the ID "DOE__JO_001". However, if there is a third Jo Doe, then it would increment to "DOE__JO_002".

Here is my code:

```
$exIDArray = @("DOE__JO_000","DOE_JO_001","SMITHNAN000","ZAHN_THO000")

$lastFive = "Doe";
$lnFive = $lastFive.toUpper()

$l = $lastFive.length

do {

$lnFive += "_";
$l++;

} while ($l -lt 5)

$firstThree = "Jo";
$fnTHree = $firstThree.toUpper()

$f = $firstThree.length

do {

$fnThree += "_";
$f++;

} while ($f -lt 3)

$numID = "00"
$increment = 0;

$skyID = $lnFive + $fnThree + $numID + $increment

$exIDArray | foreach {
 if ($skyID -in $_)
{
$increment++;
}
}

$skyID = $lnFive + $fnThree + $numID + $increment

Write-Output $skyID
```

Comment: Wouldn't John Smith be `johsmith001` and not `johnsmith001`?

Comment: yes, simple typo, not relevant to my question.

Comment: Can you update the post so that the code reflects the question (or vice versa)? The question describes one naming scheme, the code implements the opposite

Comment: Sorry, should have read everything before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the number issue. You've got a check to see if the generated ID already exists, but when it does, you're incrementing by 1, one time, and then regenerating the ID, however you aren't doing that same check again to see if the new ID also exists.

Instead, you want to do that compare/increment process in a loop that breaks on the condition that the generated user doesn't exist.

Quick note on your comparison `$exIDArray | foreach { if ($skyID -in $_) {} }`: there's no need to iterate through the `$exIDArray` because the `-in` operator does that for you, so you can just do `if ($skyID -in $exIDArray) {}`, which is what I'll be using in this example of the iteration loop:

```
$numID = "00"
$increment = 0

do {
    $increment++
    $skyID = $lnFive + $fnThree + $numID + $increment
} while ($skyID -in $exIDArray)
```

This replaces everything in your original code from `$numID = "00"` up until the `Write-Output`.

---

So with the immediate question out of the way, I want to call attention to a few other things. For one, the code as written (including my example) will only allow for userIDs from `001` through `009`, after which you'd end up with `0010` which was probably not intended.

To help with that, `$increment` should be used by itself and then padded with zeros where appropriate. [That can be done with a format string, and the `-f` operator in PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

```
$increment = 0

do {
    $increment++
    $skyID = '{0}{1}{2:d3}' -f $lnFive,$fnThree,$increment
} while ($skyID -in $exIDArray)
```

---

Regarding padding the first and last name strings, this part:

```
do {

$lnFive += "_";
$l++;

} while ($l -lt 5)
```

Strings have handy padding methods:

```
$lnFive = $lastFive.PadRight(5,'_')
$fnThree = $firstThree.PadRight(3,'_')
```

The number is the *total* length you want, and then it takes care of figuring out how many characters (if any) to add.

---

Combining all the above elements, let's look at how the modified script might look:

```
$exIDArray = @(
    "DOE__JO_000",
    "DOE_JO_001",
    "SMITHNAN000",
    "ZAHN_THO000"
)

$lastFive = "Doe"
$firstThree = "Jo"

$lnFive = $lastFive.ToUpper().PadRight(5,'_')
$fnThree = $firstThree.ToUpper().PadRight(3,'_')

$increment = 0;

do {
    $increment++
    $skyID = '{0}{1}{2:d3}' -f $lnFive,$fnThree,$increment
} while ($skyID -in $exIDArray)

Write-Output $skyID
```